# ASP.NET website (not web application) on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, appharbor

I have a website (not web application) using localDB in App_Data folder. How can I deploy it on AppHarbor?

Comment: Are you already have an account there? What have you tried?

Comment: @EugenePavlov yes i have an account and tried it. but i got stuck at creating db. i get a "invalid object name" error. i think the problem is i have the local db in app_data but somehow I need to create a db on appharbor. I added the add-on sql server but don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch to [using sequelizer](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer), the AppHarbor database-as-a-service add-on. Trying to permanently store data on the AppHarbor worker filesystems is not going to work because they are wiped on each deploy.

If you already have a LocalDB database with data, you should be able to transfer it to AppHarbor using [SQL Server bulk copy](https://github.com/appharbor/AppHarbor-SqlServerBulkCopy).

Comment: i am getting NULLReferenceException at line 106. any ideas? @friism

Comment: i have tried this and i was able to create the tables but couldn't add the data. http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/releases/view/32334

Comment: friism, just adding another comment that i meant i got it working with sqlazuremw. couldn't get the cmd line tool working. you should add a link to this tool on the website i think. it is really a saver. the cmd line tool might be good too but it is hard to use it since there are so many options and it gets hard to manage